# How do I locate spouse's misplaced iPhone 6S?

Tags: icloud, iphone, find-my-iphone

My husband and I have iPhone6 but his is a 6S.  He misplaced his iPhone and I want to help him locate it.  How do I do that?  With my iPad & iPhone I can go to find iPhone and see my devices.  How do I add his iPhone to my devices?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply add a device to Find My iPhone - though Family Sharing will enable that automatically. Think of find my device like data backups, you need to set them up before you lose the item in question.

Unless you are already set up for [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060), which would allow you to see the location of all the family's devices, then from an iPhone using Find My iPhone, or a web browser using https://www.icloud.com/#find , sign into **his** Apple ID.

Otherwise, check with your cellular carrier or check wireless networks to see if the phone is joined to any known networks.

Comment: This assumes, of course, that Find My iPhone has been enabled on the 6S.

Comment: true... I hadn't considered that anyone **wouldn't** enable it within 5 minutes of getting it out of the box :/ at 800 quid/bucks/euros you really want that set up fast